# Remove float duplicates from a list of tuples created by zip

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, tuples, drop-duplicates

I create a list of tuples by zipping three lists together, data pairs:

```
 XYZip = list(zip(XaData, Y1aData, Y2aData))
```

```py
[
    (0.001625625, 4.782947316198166, -0.011032947316198166),
    (-2.5e-06, 4.783447358402665, 0.020216552641597337),
    (0.0008137499999999999, 4.782997384780477, -0.017282997384780476),
    (0.00081, 4.783247405882726, 0.020216752594117274),
    (0.001625625, 4.782066023993667, -0.011032066023993668), 
    (0.00324625, 4.780809700135795, 0.03271919029986421),
    ...,
    (19.4121325, 4.653511649011105, 1.1703464883509889)
]
```

I need to get rid of the tuples where the XaData value is a duplicate, like this one 0.001625625. The whole tuple (0.001625625, 4.782066023993667, -0.011032066023993668) needs to go. Order doesn't matter. I can sort in a second step. I tried set() to no avail.

Data will be fed to a scipy.CubicSpline function where x need to be strictly increasing and will not accept duplicates!

I tried...

```
XYZip = list(zip(XaData, Y1aData, Y2aData))
XYUnique = set(XYZip)
XYSorted = sorted(XYUnique)
XaData, Y1aData, Y2aData = zip(*XYSorted)
```

...obviously not removing the tuples with the duplicate XaData value.

This is what I need in the first step:

```py
[
    (0.001625625, 4.782947316198166, -0.011032947316198166),
    (-2.5e-06, 4.783447358402665, 0.020216552641597337),
    (0.0008137499999999999, 4.782997384780477, -0.017282997384780476),
    (0.00081, 4.783247405882726, 0.020216752594117274),
    (0.00324625, 4.780809700135795, 0.03271919029986421),
    ...,
    (19.4121325, 4.653511649011105, 1.1703464883509889)
]
```

Comment: The whole concept of a "float duplicate" is kind of suspect.  Floats can be so close together they look identical, without actually being equal.

Answer (score 1):

### Why set of tuple is not return correct answer in this case

```
(0.001625625, 4.782947316198166, -0.011032947316198166)
            ,      |           ,          |
        same,      not same    ,          not same
            ,      |           ,          | 
(0.001625625, 4.782066023993667, -0.011032066023993668)

# so

(0.001625625, 4.782947316198166, -0.011032947316198166) 
# not equal 
(0.001625625, 4.782066023993667, -0.011032066023993668)
```

It is easy and straightforward if you use pandas instead.

Example:

```py
x = 1,1,2,3,4,5
y = 1,2,3,4,5,6
z = 1,3,5,7,9,11

pd.DataFrame(zip(x, y, z), columns=["x","y","z"]).drop_duplicates(subset='x', keep="last")
```

step 1
create DataFrame

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(x, y, z), columns=["x","y","z"])
```

|  | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 5 | 5 | 6 | 11 |

step 2
drop duplicates [Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='x', keep="last")
```

|  | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 5 | 5 | 6 | 11 |

drop 1, 1, 1 because `keep="last"`

Combine to your code

```py
XYZip = list(zip(XaData, Y1aData, Y2aData))

# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(XYZip, columns=["XaData","Y1aData","Y2aData"])

# removing the duplicate on XaData value.
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='XaData', keep="last")

# if you want to convert to list of tuple 

result = [tuple(i) for i in df.values]
# result = [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 7), (4, 5, 9), (5, 6, 11)]
```

### or

Use dictionary of tuple instead.

```py
temp = {i_x: (i_y, i_z) for i_x, i_y, i_z in zip(x, y, z)}
[((i,)+temp[i]) for i in temp]
```

step 1
convert x y z to dictionary  (key x because I need to delete duplicate on x)

```py
temp = {i_x: (i_y, i_z) for i_x, i_y, i_z in zip(x, y, z)}
```

step 2
convert to list of tuple

```
[((i,)+temp[i]) for i in temp]
```

result

```py
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 5), (3, 4, 7), (4, 5, 9), (5, 6, 11)]

# drop (1,1,1) because (1, 1, 1) and (1, 2, 3) are same in first element.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by checking if value is already in list like

```
if x not in x_list:
    x_list.append(x)
    y_list.append(y)
    z_list.append(z)
```

That solved it. All constructs with set() failed and scipy spline interpolation threw an error about not strictly increasing x-values.